# Export aspx page to pdf and sent it via mail in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I want to send aspx page via email. So i converted it into pdf. The problrm is the pdf is getting created before the data is saved. So when i open the pdf my testboxes are empty. Please find me a solution. Below is the code am using. Also i want to send the pdf file as attachment.

```
     protected void SendMail()
    {

        var userName = "4.n-4@gmail.com";

        var toAddress = YourEmail.Text.ToString();

        const string Password = "Mypassword123#";

        string subject = YourSubject.Text.ToString();
        string body = "From: " + YourName.Text + "\n";
        body += "Email: " + YourEmail.Text + "\n";
        body += "Subject: " + YourSubject.Text + "\n";
        body += "Question: \n" + Comments.Text + "\n";

        var smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient();
        {
            smtp.Host = "10.238.52.240";
            smtp.Port = 25;
            smtp.EnableSsl = false;
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = System.Net.Mail.SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, Password);
            smtp.Timeout = 20000;
        }

        smtp.Send(userName, toAddress, subject, body);
    }

     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf"; 
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=TestPage.pdf");
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache); 
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw); 
        this.Page.RenderControl(hw); 
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());
        Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f); 
        HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream); 
        pdfDoc.Open(); 
        htmlparser.Parse(sr); 

        Response.Write(pdfDoc);


         try
        {
             SendMail();

            DisplayMessage.Text = "Your Comments after sending the mail";
            DisplayMessage.Visible = true;
            YourSubject.Text = "";
            YourEmail.Text = "";
            YourName.Text = "";
            Comments.Text = "";
            pdfDoc.Close();
            Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the rest of your code behind, but I'm guessing you are missing adequate PostBack handling.  When you click the submit button, the page is first posted (that is the 'PostBack' - the entire page life cycle is re-processed, including the `Page_Load` event; re-initializing the page), so when you arrive in your button's Click event afterwards, the form and your textboxes will be empty.

You can read up on ASP.NET Page Life Cycle on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: I called the function first ,send mail. still the form is not getting saved. Can you explain it with an example please.

Comment: Please edit your original question and add the code you use to fill out the text boxes when you load your page.  I.e. your 'main' method (usually `Page_Load`).